# Rails: How to convert hash of array of objects to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm a java and Js developer, so I'm completetly new to rails and ruby. In one of my project I'm using rails to consume an api and return in back to js. I'm converting the api response to a model in ruby.

Now, it's in format of `{KEY1=>[{array of objects(my model)}], KEY2=>[{array of objects(my model)}]}`

Also the keys to model is in snake_case. My requirement is to loop through this and convert this into JSON with camel case keys.

Api response after converting to model: `{ KEY1=>[{@person_name:"abc", @person_id="123"}],KEY2:[{@personName:"bca", @person_id="231"}] }`

Desired output: `{ KEY1:[{personName:"abc", personId:"123"}],KEY2:[{personName:"bca",personId:"231"}] }`

I tried using .map and .transform_values till now, but don't know where I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Minor note: your desired output is not a valid JSON

Comment: Just use JSON.generate to convert your hash to JSON. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-generate

Comment: Does it take care of converting keys to camel case? @dbugger

Comment: @AbhishekP - To clarify, you want to convert a list of models into json, and transofrm all the keys using camelcase?

Comment: Yes, exactly @BroiSatse

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your `ApplicationRecord` class:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def serializable_hash(options = {})
    hash = super
    return hash unless options[:camelize]

    hash.deep_transform_keys { |key| key.to_s.camelize(options[:camelize]) }
  end
end
```

This will allow you to call `to_json(camelize: :lower)` on pretty much any object:

```
{
  KEY1: Person.where(...),
  KEY2: Person.where(...),
}.to_json(camelize: :lower)
```

To automatically serialize the whole collection

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```rb
{ 
  KEY1: Person.where(...).select(:name, :id).map { |p| Hash[p.serializable_hash.map { |key, value| ["#{p.model_name.name.downcase}#{key.capitalize}", value] }] }, 
  KEY2: Person.where(...).select(:name, :id).map { |p| Hash[p.serializable_hash.map { |key, value| ["#{p.model_name.name.downcase}#{key.capitalize}", value] }] }
}.to_json
```